# JS equivalent to Ruby's return if

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement

In Ruby i can use `return if variable != 1`
as example to not run the code comming after the return. I need to do the same in JS but i dont want to use a full `if (variable != 1) { My code here }` statement.
Is that possible?

Comment: yep, and so what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `return` after the `if` statement:

```
if (variable != 1) return;
// more code here
```

Comment: That was exactly what im looking for. JS syntax is really weird if you comming from ruby which has the best sytax of all scripting languages i seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

Put `return` after a one-line `if`:

```
if (variable !== 1) return;
```

Demonstration:

```js
function test() {
  if (variable != 1) return;
  console.log("Variable equals one"); //Will never be run
}

var variable = 2;
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
if (i !== 1) return 'True';
```

2.

```
return (i !== 1) ? 'True' : 'False';
```

3.

```
if (i !== 1) { console.log('Not equal'); } // else { }
```

*Example*

```js
function test() {
    let i = 1;
    if (i !== 1) {
        console.log('Not equal to 1');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

console.log(test());
```

*Single*

```js
function test() {
    let i = 1;
    if (i !== 1) return 'True';
}

console.log(test());
```

Ternary operator

```js
function test() {
    let i = 1;
    return (i !== 1) ? 'True' : 'False';
}

console.log(test());
```